# multiple calls to the renderer do not work

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the last two months i have learned a lot about three.js and javascript. i have now gone deeper into the handling of shaders and i once saw a nice example of creating procedural planets on the web. I find spherical geometries interesting because their non-euclidean geometry makes them a nice challenge for textures.

I have shown the main code here. my problem is that the texture rendering doesn't work.
I have tested the individual components of my program. The shader and the planet class, all functions work correctly.
the problem is the renderer. I need this to display the scene but also to create the textures. When in the function
`textureGeneratorMaterial` (below) `renderer.render(textureScene, textureCamera, texture, true);` is activate, I only get a black screen. There after the function `renderer.render(scene, camera);` is called, I mean that the normal scene should be seen. Does the program remain trapped in the texture scene? Why does `renderer.render(scene, camera)` not work, if the renderer is also called in `textureGeneratorMaterial`?
I've already tried to create a second renderer, but that doesn't work either. At the moment i don't know what to do, because i don't understand the cause. Someone knows why the renderer doesn't want the way I want?

```
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, container;
var sunLight, ambientlight;

var test1, test2, test3, test4;
    
function main() {
init();
animate();
}


function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
             
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight; 
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.enabled = true;
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    
    //-------------

    sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(new THREE.Color(0xffffff), 1.0);
    sunLight.position.set(100, 0, 0);
    scene.add(sunLight);

    ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xF0F0F0 ); // soft white light 
    scene.add( ambientlight );

    var maps = generateTextures(); //--here is the problem---
    
    /*  -----used ro check "function textureGeneratorMaterial(index)" works------
    
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024, 1024), 
            textureGeneratorMaterial(0)
        );
    scene.add( plane );
    */
    
    /*-----used ro check "Planet class" works------
    
    for(var i = 0; i <6;i++){
    maps.textureMaps[i].texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/Cay_sand.jpeg");
    maps.bumpMaps[i].texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/Cay_sand.jpeg");
    }
    */
    
    scene.add(new Planet(5, maps.textureMaps, maps.bumpMaps));  // works correct


}//-------End init----------


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );  
    render();
    
}//-------End animate----------

function render() {
    
    
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = test1;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = test2;
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = test3;
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = test4;
    
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 

}//-------End render----------

function generateTextures() {
    var textureMaps = [];
    var bumpMaps = [];
    var resolution = 1024;
    
    for (var index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
        
        var texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(resolution, resolution, {minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat});
        
        var textureCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-resolution/2, resolution/2, resolution/2, -resolution/2, -100, 100);
        textureCamera.position.z = 10;
        
        var textureScene = new THREE.Scene();
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.PlaneGeometry(resolution, resolution), 
            textureGeneratorMaterial(index)
        );
        plane.position.z = -10;
        textureScene.add(plane);

    //  renderer.render(textureScene, textureCamera, texture, true);
        
        var buffer = new Uint8Array(resolution * resolution * 4);
        var gl = renderer.getContext();
        gl.readPixels( 0, 0, resolution, resolution, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        
        textureMaps.push(texture);
        bumpMaps.push({image: {data: buffer, height: resolution, width: resolution}});
        
    }
    return {textureMaps: textureMaps, bumpMaps: bumpMaps};
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that the scene in generateTexrures displays on its own without being in a texture? Did you try replacing the texture with a picture to see if that worked?

Comment: yes i have and it all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found a solution. I was convinced that it was up to the renderer and that it would remain trapped in the texture target when it was called up for the first time.
In three.js there is the possibility to reset the render target and if you do that, three.js seems to see it as in need of initialization and accepts the call to the renderer to render the main scene.

I added this line: `renderer.setRenderTarget(null);`

See below

```
function generateTextures() {
    var textureMaps = [];
    var bumpMaps = [];
    var resolution = 2048;
    
    for (var index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
        
        var texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(resolution, resolution, {minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat});
        
        var textureCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-resolution/2, resolution/2, resolution/2, -resolution/2, -100, 100);
        textureCamera.position.z = 10;
        
        var textureScene = new THREE.Scene();
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.PlaneGeometry(resolution, resolution), 
            textureGeneratorMaterial(index)
        );
        plane.position.z = -10;
        textureScene.add(plane);

        renderer.render(textureScene, textureCamera, texture, true);
        
        var buffer = new Uint8Array(resolution * resolution * 4);
        var gl = renderer.getContext();
        gl.readPixels( 0, 0, resolution, resolution, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        
        textureMaps.push(texture);
        bumpMaps.push({image: {data: buffer, height: resolution, width: resolution}});
        renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
    }
    return {textureMaps: textureMaps, bumpMaps: bumpMaps};
}
```

In older versions like the example I saw, this wasn't necessary. But this is not meant as a criticism. It's a clean solution. So three always knows that there is a need for renderer action.

Comment: Yeah, the render target parameter of `render()` was removed some releases ago so it's now the necessary to define via `setRenderTarget()` whether a render target should be used or not.